# Simple XPath question about root node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have just started learning XPath and I am learning the language without the abbreviation first.

> When a location path starts with the character '/' the initial context node is forces to be the root node...

Sample xml from book:

```
<widget type="gadget">
    ...
</widget>
```

If I am supposed to write the XPath so I get the type attribute why do I have to write:

/child::widget/attribute::type

and not like this /attribute::type

Have I misunderstood something about the root node or? Because I thought '/' and widget was the same...

Thank you

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes

> Each element node has an associated
>   set of attribute nodes; the element is
>   the parent of each of these attribute
>   nodes; however, an attribute node is
>   not a child of its parent element.

Only element nodes have attributes.

The root node is not an element. From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node

> The root node is the root of the tree.
>   A root node does not occur except as
>   the root of the tree. The element node
>   for the document element is a child of
>   the root node. The root node also has
>   as children processing instruction and
>   comment nodes for processing
>   instructions and comments that occur
>   in the prolog and after the end of the
>   document element.

Thus you cannot select attributes of the root node like in `/@*` or `/attribute::*`

You ask:

> Have I misunderstood something about
>   the root node or?

Yes. You should not confuse the root node (an abstraction) with the document element (some times also called the element root)

Answer (score 2):

> If I am supposed to write the XPath so
>   I get the type attribute why do I have
>   to write:
>
> ```
> /child::widget/attribute::type
> ```
>
> and not like this
>
> ```
> /attribute::type
> ```

**The XPath expression**:

```
/attribute::type
```

**means**:

*Select the* `type` *attribute of the root node of the XML document*.

However, a root node doesn't have attributes (as per **[W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#attribute-nodes)**), therefore, the above XPath expression selects nothing.

**You want**:

```
/widget/@type
```

**This means**:

*Select the* `type` *attribute of the top element* (named `widget`) *of the XML document*.

> Have I misunderstood something about
>   the root node or? Because I thought
>   '/' and widget was the same...

**Always remember that the root node `/` is not an element.** as per the **[W3C XPath Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node)**.